# Linuxのカーネルソースってどこから落とせますか

Tags: linux

Linuxのカーネルソースってどこから落とせますか？
もしかして、落とさなくても使っているLinux内のフォルダにすでにありますか？

プログラマとして読んでおいたほうがいいそうなので。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.kernel.org/)からダウンロードできます。